# how to comment the selected block of code at a time in Vim?

Tags: python, vim

I know how to comment one line,which is quite easy

```
:autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <leader>c I#<esc>
```

but how to comment multiple lines at one time by a mapping shortcut? I cannot think out it

i.e, I enter v mode and select a block of code , can I use a mapping shortcut to comment them at one time ?

the comment of a block of code means, put the # at every line of the selected block ,like

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 4
```

to

```
#a = 2
#b = 3
#c = 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a visual mode mapping to operate on a visual selection. Normal mode mappings start with `n`, insert mode mappings start with `i`, and visual mode mappings start with `x` (yeah…).

For this to work you will need `:help :normal` to execute your normal mode command on every line in the given range:

```
xnoremap <leader>c :normal I#<CR>
```

So…

```
augroup myStuff
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType python nnoremap <buffer> <leader>c I#<esc>
    autocmd FileType python xnoremap <buffer> <leader>c :normal I#<CR>
augroup END
```

Comment: and how to uncomment the line quickly , I tried `autocmd FileType python <leader>C 0x` but not work

Comment: Your question is about commenting. Ask another question about uncommenting.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you might want to take a look at [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter), which does all the heavy-lifting for you.